# How to load a n-triple file in virtuoso using Jena API

Tags: java, rdf, jena, virtuoso

`Jena` has the `read` method that helps loading an ontology from file in the model. Is there something similar for virtuoso using the `Jena API`?

That will greatly helps me test virtuoso on my already existing ontology store in n-triple format.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read an ontology from a Virtuoso server, you will need the "JDBC"-like drivers for Virtuoso, as explained here: http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider
The download is at http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSDownload#Jena%20Provider
though I preferred to compile it from source -

then you can do something like:

```
VirtDataset dataSet = new VirtDataset("jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111/charset=UTF-8/","user","pass");
Model baseModel = dataSet.getNamedModel("http://my.graph.name/");
OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, baseModel);
```

This should allow access to all your RDF-Triples stored in Virtuoso (one graph at a time). 
If you just want the RDF, leave out the last line with the "OntModel" construction. Same if the store is very large, as it loads the complete ontology into RAM.

Comment: I've the jdbc driver, but I wonder how to read the ontology from a file on disk ? in jena you have `model.read` to do that. How to do the same with virtuoso ?

Comment: I guess I did not understand your question. Do you want to read the ontology from virtuoso or from a file? And if from a file, how does virtuoso come into play?

Answer (score 1):

The Jena `read` method may be used also with Virtuoso Jena provider.
Like the next:

```
try {
  String nfile = "1.nt";
  Model model = VirtModel.openDatabaseModel("load:test", "jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111", "dba", "dba");
  InputStream in = FileManager.get().open( nfile );
  if (in == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + nfile + " not found");
  }
  model.read(new InputStreamReader(in), null, "N-TRIPLE");
  model.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Ex="+e);
}
```